# write table html attributes into an equivalent css

Tags: css

How can I write the following html table attributes into an equivalent css?

```
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" border="0" style="width:600px;border: 1px solid #cccccc"></table>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is a equivalent to your code:

```css
table {
  background-color:#fff;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:600px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To see the (non existing) difference, here your example with a row:

```html
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" border="0" style="width:600px;border: 1px solid #cccccc">
  <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

So simple. Look at the following.

```
<table class="test">

.test
{
 background-color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0px auto;
 width:600px;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width:600px;
}
```

This should do it.